# Matrix Inequality Existence

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$, $S$ and $N$ be positive integers. Consider the following matrices:

- $\mathbf A\in \mathbb R^{R\times R}$,
- $\mathbf B\in \mathbb R^{R\times N}$,
- $\mathbf C\in \mathbb R^{R\times S}$,
- $\mathbf D\in \mathbb R^{N\times S}$.

Suppose also that

- $\mathbf A\geq\mathbf0$,
- $\mathbf B\geq\mathbf0$,
- $[\mathbf A\,|\,\mathbf B]\mathbf 1_{R+N}=\mathbf 1_R$, where $\mathbf 1_x$ is a vector of $x$ ones,
- $\mathbf A\mathbf C+\mathbf B\mathbf D\gg\mathbf C$ ($\gg$ means that every  element is strictly greater than).

I want to find a matrix $\mathbf F\in\mathbb R^{R\times N}$ such that

- $\mathbf F\geq\mathbf0$,
- $\mathbf F\mathbf 1_N=\mathbf 1_R$,
- $\mathbf F\mathbf D\gg\mathbf C$.

Intuitively, I want to shift the probability weight from $\mathbf A$ to $\mathbf B$ without affecting the original inequality.

Does such a matrix necessarily exist? (Note: I wish to avoid assuming that $(\mathbf I-\mathbf A)$ is invertible.) If so, how to find it? It might boil down to Farkas's lemma or some Perron–Frobenius theory at the end of the day, but I'm not sure. Thank you very much in advance for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Update: I think I have an affirmative answer, but the proof is surprisingly complicated.